# Shortcodes on my website stops working after theme update

Tags: posts, themes, shortcode

Hi I am using pagelines theme on my website and have updated the theme today. I am showing a download form here on the below page using a shortcode

http://socrato.com/resources/ebooks-and-tools/6-internet-trends-to-watch-in-education-free-eguide/

The shortcode on the above page does not work any more and other short codes for post-content id=x works

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: [Support requests for third-party themes and plugins are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You'd be better off asking in the relevant theme / plugin developer's support channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most likely your `[download_ebook_lead_form ret_url=""]` shortcode was defined in functions.php in your theme parent folder, and during update the file was somehow replaced with new one. If you have backup of previous version of your theme check its functions.php and look for `add_shortcode( 'download_ebook_lead_form'...)`. If you find it there just copy entire function to functions.php in updated theme.